# cannot open files since workspaces act weird

Tags: filesystem, graphics, workspaces

Yesterday, I began having difficulties opening files, both when trying to upload things to the internet and when trying to open files in for instance LibreOffice. Instead of the popup window which asks what file to open (which showed in the activity bar, but weren't visible on the screen), on the workspaces symbol, there would light up half a workspace. It looks like something covers 1,5 workspace. When I try to go to workspace 2, half of workspace 1 is visible, and the rest of the screen is disturbed.

I have tried rebooting, turning off the computer completely, getting rid of LibreOffice and then re-installing it again, and opening several different files. Nothing makes the problem go away. Sometimes the graphics become weird (one version on top of another repeated times), and sometimes nothing happens for a very long time, except a random scroll down bar appear at a random place.

I have tried to take screenshots of some of the problems, to cover most of the problems, so there's nothing wrong with the underlying processor, but there seems to be something wrong with the graphics.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is rather embarrassing, but after I thought I had checked everything, it turned out there was one thing I hadn't checked: one cable needed to be jiggled a little. Now things work as good as new. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Good find.  +1 for answering your own question!